# What is the punishment of zina in this world, and in the hereafter?

Tags: zina

I know someone who is having relationships with multiple girls. He is a celebrity.

I got to know three girls with whom he is having relationships at the same time! No doubt there are more! He promises them to marry, and lies a lot, that he doesn't have any other relationships. He says that he is very trustful. And he promised the same thing with all of them.

He says,he prays four wakt prayer, and shows off a lot. On the other hand, he is lying constantly.

He always invites them to his apartment. He forces them, and do emotional blackmail to have sex.

I know one of them is still virgin, and he broke up with her because of it. She wanted to expose his character, but she is afraid that he may do any harm to her. Since he is a national personality, and has more power than her.

Since, no one is still coming out to expose his evidences for the similar cases, then he'll easily continue whatever he was doing, without having any punishment. (As Islam rules 100 lashes etc)

And there are many people like him, who are hiding their evil deeds with their power.

In this type of circumstances, what will be the punishment of these people in this life, and in the hereafter? as they are hiding their deeds easily, though betraying many girls.

Zajakallah Khayer..

Comment: We are not a site for judging others, even if we were in any position to do so based on such a one-sided third-party telling of the situation.

Answer (score 3):

In this world if proven such crime is committed.
If married, then death by stoning.
If unmarried, then 100 lashes.

However, God is very forgiving and one can repent as soon as possible.

In the hereafter, it's burning in hell where the fire is almost 70 times strong than earth and locks/chains maybe attached to parts of body for extra punishment. This is if a person does not repent and sincerely ask for forgiveness from Allah.

Comment: It would be nice to see references quoted as this is a very delicate topic. More similar content can be found [here](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/27259/ruling-on-the-things-that-lead-to-zina-kissing-touching-and-being-alone-together) and in this [answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1453/11938).