# Is fingering by boyfriend considered Haram or Zina?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, allah, sex, zina

One of my friends went out with her boyfriend . They both are going to get married so her boyfriend due to the moment of heat fingered her astagfiruallh she has regret about it . I wanted to know weather it is Haram or Zina . Please answer my question and please tell me how can she overcome through it

Comment: Read this to learn what Zina actually is: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/816/what-actions-would-constitute-zina

Answer (score 1):

*One of my friends went out with her boyfriend . They both are going to get married so her boyfriend due to the moment of heat fingered her **astagfiruallh** she has regret about it . I wanted to know weather it is Haram or Zina . Please answer my question and please tell me how can she overcome through it*.

Sister you answered your own question by saying "**astagfiruallh**" it is a sin but not zina because, Zina is unlawful sexual intercourse between man and women.

> the moment of heat **fingered** her

It is not actual sexual intercourse. So it is not Zina but is a Sin.

> how can she overcome through it

Just ask for forgiveness.

Answer (score 1):

She's regretting that is the sign of iman

Don't worry if she asked for forgiveness of Allah and make a decision not committing it again then she will as pure as she a new born

May Allah forgive us

Answer (score 1):

They're going to marry but either way it's a sin, she is regretting it so if she asked for forgiveness it's fine now.
If you have iman in Allah and not repeat the sin again she may be forgiven, may Allah forgive her and us all.
Hope i helped you(:

Answer (score 0):

Zina is haram and having a boyfriend is haram
Firstly you need to get married to him if you really love him but if he refuses then break up and leave him.You will not let some boy be the cause of you crying on judgement day are you?
Repent الله is the most forgiving
Please go look at these surahs and verses they will comfort you
In the quran
Surah al zumar verse 53
3:159
42:43
24:24
Those are just some like only very few
Thinking that الله cannot forgive you is a sin as you are glorifying your sin over him