# Ejaculation on vagina without penetration is zina or not

Tags: zina

If a male ejaculates on vagina without penetration is it still zina and shoud hadd punishment should be carried out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What actions would constitute zina?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/816/what-actions-would-constitute-zina)

Answer (score 0):

Alsalam alikum, in short yes it is zina. Zina is not only penetration, but Zina is also every act that is sexual and intimate, and Zina is not one grade there are multiple grades to Zina.

Everything from touching (like holding hands) to sexual intercourse counts as Zina.

Although not everything is punishable by law, what you said counts as greater Zina which is punishable by law.

Comment: But there is no sexual intercoarse ..is Hadd punishment applicable ?

Comment: Talking about punishment by LAW ... Tazeer punishment  or Hadd(100 lashes) punisment

Comment: Plz reply ..Jazak Allah